# Cannot add Flyout Footer in Xamarin forms app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-application, app-shell

I have a xamarin forms application and I want to add a footer to the flyout menu. After reading the official documentation it should be straightforward, just adding a few lines into the AppShell.xaml like so:

```
<Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label HeightRequest="300" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
```

This works perfectly fine when I tried it in a new project, but for some reason, it doesn't work in my current application giving this error:
**Error XLS0415 The attachable property 'FlyoutFooterTemplate' was not found in type 'Shell'.**

I tried to find the definition of FlyoutHeaderTemplate and I found this in **Shell [from metadata]** file:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqZub.png

```
public Shell();
...
public DataTemplate FlyoutHeaderTemplate { get; set; }
public FlyoutHeaderBehavior FlyoutHeaderBehavior { get; set; }
public object FlyoutHeader { get; set; }
```

There should be a similar definition for both, Header and Footer, but there is only one for the Header. The file cannot be edited and I was not able to locate it either. Any ideas why the definition for Footer is missing, how can I add it, or workarounds?

PS: Adding the footer from C# code doesn't work either and I tried to clean/rebuild and resetting both, PC and VS.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

First, Confirm that you can add a simple Header:

```
<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <Label Text="This is the header." />
</Shell.FlyoutFooter>
```

If that doesn't work, then you are doing something fundamentally wrong - post the code for the `<Shell>` XAML, within which you added those lines. Make sure you include those lines, to show where in the XAML they are. Make sure they are between `<Shell>` and `</Shell>`, but not nested inside some deeper node. For example, they musn't be inside a `<StackLayout>` or `<ContentView>` or other container - they must be direct children of the `<Shell>`.

---

2. 

Unless you are doing something fancy, you don't need a `Template`.

Try simply:

```
<Shell.FlyoutFooter>
    <Label HeightRequest="300" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
</Shell.FlyoutFooter>
```

---

3. 

If 1) above works, but not 2), then your project is referencing an out-of-date version of `Shell`. Fixes:

A. Check that project's `Xamarin.Forms nuget` doesn't need an Update. (Solution / Manage Nugets.)
B. OR delete `bin` and `obj` folders. Then Rebuild Solution.
C. Worst case, start with a new project, in which you are able to use that functionality, and add back in all your files.

Comment: I just found out myself too, I have an old Xamarin version (4.6), the footer was added in version 5 as said here:
https://newreleases.io/project/github/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/release/beta-5.0.0-pre3
Thank you.